# How to encode string to hex for sending downlink to iot devices?

Tags: python, hex, iot

According to this document

[image]

I need to send downlink of type `080100ff` to open the supply of the socket.

However, I can not send `080100ff` since I got this error `The payload field is not a valid hexadecimal payload in upper case.`

Here is my so far works in python

'080100ff'.encode('utf-8').hex() -> 3038303130306666

I can send it now, but I think it is incorrectly hex encoded because the device is not turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are converting a hexadecimal string (080100ff) into hexadecimal value. You already have the hexadecimal value, it is: 080100ff

Would that work?

```
bytes.fromhex('080100ff')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be maybe you need to try, *080100FF*

Comment: As the error message says ‘not in *uppercase*